# FFTW wrapper and Matlab

Tags: c#, matlab, fft, fftw

FFTW wrapper:

```
plan = fftwf.dft_1d (n, pin, pout, fftw_direction.Backward, fftw_flags.Estimate);
```

Matlab:

```
g = fft (samples, 2048)
```

Now I get almost correct results, but the `Im` values from FFTW wrapper have different sign. If i read values from then end of `g` to beggining - values will be ok.
Why FFT from Matlab is different than FFT from FFTW? Is any parameter to tell FFTW to order data?

Comment: You have the direction as backward in the first case, so it's an inverse FFT. Change it to forward.

Comment: You correct, I don't understand this FFT things : /

Comment: You'll have a tough time using FFTs in your code if you don't understand the basics of FFTs - it would probably be worth spending a little time reading up on the fundamentals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the direction as backward in the first case, so it's an inverse FFT. Change it to forward:

```
plan = fftwf.dft_1d (n, pin, pout, fftw_direction.Forward, fftw_flags.Estimate);
```